AccessDeniedException in Tomcat 10.1.18 while tomcat migrating from java ee jars to jakarta ee jars from webapps-javaee folder to webapps folder
Recently I upgraded to Tomcat 10.1.18 version and using default jakartaee jars conversion by creating webapps-javaee folder inside tomcat.
22-Jul-2024 12:41:33.139 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.jakartaee.Migration.execute Migration completed successfully in [64,341] milliseconds
22-Jul-2024 12:41:33.140 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.migrateLegacyApp Migration failure
    java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: D:\apache-tomcat\webapps-javaee\new15138380162572471632.tmp -> D:\apache-tomcat\webapps\Processor
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:89)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:103)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileCopy.move(WindowsFileCopy.java:395)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.move(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:292)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.move(Files.java:1422)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.migrateLegacyApp(HostConfig.java:1257)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$MigrateApp.run(HostConfig.java:2008)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.migrateLegacyApps(HostConfig.java:1213)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:421)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1661)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:309)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:114)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:402)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:345)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:893)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:845)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:866)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:433)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:917)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:795)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:347)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:478)
22-Jul-2024 12:41:33.412 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.jakartaee.Migration.execute Performing migration from source [D:\apache-tomcat\webapps-javaee\Rest] to destination [D:\apache-tomcat\webapps-javaee\new4445914546884495863.tmp] with Jakarta EE specification profile [TOMCAT]

When I am trying to deploy my war folder inside webapps-javaee folder, few are migrating successfully and few are throwing the access denied exception as I given above. This issue also some times coming and sometimes not coming.
Is this because of War Folders instead for war files ?
Is this happens because of large war folders ?
I would be grateful if any one can help me in this.
